# Google API 401 response in Angular despite the exact same request returning correctly when sent manually?

Tags: angularjs, google-api, google-books

I'm trying to access the Google Books API from within Angular using the following request:
`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=test&key=(my api key)`

When I use Postman to GET this URL, I receive the correct data with a 200 response. When I do it in Angular, I'm getting 401 Invalid Credentials no matter how I try.

Here's my Angular code:

```
$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=test&key=(my api key)')
 .then(function success(response) {
   //
  }, function failure(response) {
   //
  });
```

Can anyone advise me on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what is "my api key"?  it should be a public api key http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-create-public-api-key/

Comment: Have you used the network inspector in your developer tools to compare the two requests?